# Oracle Get 12 records from table depending on the selected year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has the resulting data by month, which consists of the following columns:

ID, Month, Year, Sum of objects

It is required to output 12 rows from this table according to the following principle:

- If a year from the past is selected (for example, 2022, 2021, etc.), then output only 12 lines that will correspond to the months of the selected year.
- If the current year is selected, then given that it is March, then 3 months of the current year plus 9 months of the last 2022 should be displayed. In April 2023, 4 months of 2023 and 8 months of last year should be displayed.

My database is Oracle.

Thanks.

I tried to use case in where and dependencies and further, if the current year is selected, count like this: between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-12) and sysdate

and if another month is selected, then output data for the specified other year. But alas, it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one row per month for each year, a query like

```plsql
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE Year <= givenyear
    ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC
    FETCH FIRST 12 ROWS ONLY;
```

should do the job for for Oracle versions > 12c

for older versions this should work :

```plsql
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    ( SELECT *
      FROM mytable
      WHERE Year <= givenyear
      ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC )
    where ROWNUM <= 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is one row per month per year and your input is being passed via the `:year` bind variable:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  (   :year < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
       AND year = :year
       )
OR     (   :year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
       AND (  (   year = :year
              AND month <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
              )
           OR (   year = :year - 1
              AND month >  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
              )
           )
       )
```